# javascript how to save base64 data as png

Tags: javascript

I am using the `getDirectoryHandle` and `getFileHandle` APIs. I want to save a picture in the specified directory. I have the base64 data of the picture, but I don’t know how to save the base64 as a picture

```js
const hDir = await showDirectoryPicker();
const hImageFile = await hDir.getFileHandle("test.png", {
  create: true,
});
const w$ = await hImageFile.createWritable();
await w$.write( canvas.toDataURL('image/png') );
await w$.close();
```

I tried:

```js
await w$.write( atob(canvas.toDataURL('image/png')) );
```

but the saved picture is not recognized.

Comment: is this on nodeJS? are you able to use fs module?

Comment: @lanxion Chrome 87, not in nodejs environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just miss some code.

Under Chrome console, you can print the DataURL of

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
```

and you will see it begins with

```
data:image/png;base64,
```

This is the header of DataURL, not the header of image file.
So we need to remove it, by ignore the 22 charactors

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/png').substring(22)
```

and then turn the string contents into byte array

```
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

finally,
replace

```
await w$.write( atob(canvas.toDataURL('image/png')) );
```

with

```
await w$.write( _base64ToArrayBuffer(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').substring(22)));
```

enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.toBlob(async function (blob) {
  const w$ = await hImageFile.createWritable();
  await w$.write(blob);
  await w$.close();
});
```